# How can i implement paging rest spring without repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, mocking, paging

I'm trying to create a mock service I've created the rest endpoint

```
/OrderLine/lists/_generic?limit=3&_paging=NEXT
```

on service layer I'm doing

```
    List<OrderLineDTO> listPOL = generateMockOrderLinesByCount(Constants.COUNT);
```

so i how do i  apply pagination in this mock data without using repository

I'm trying approach first convert list to page but doen't seem helpful or may be i'm trying in wrong direction please suggest.

```
Page<OrderLineDTO> listToPage(List<OrderLineDTO> list, Pageable pageable) {
        int start = (int) pageable.getOffset();

        int end = (int) ((start + pageable.getPageSize()) > list.size() ? list.size()
                : (start + pageable.getPageSize()));
        Page<OrderLineDTO> page = new PageImpl<OrderLineDTO>(list.subList(start, end), pageable,
                list.size());
        return page;
    }
```

My final json response is like i need to add fields on the basis of pass limit and maximum count will be some static value let say 100. so from total 100 fields which means listPOL.size()=100 and i need to fetch this 100 on the basis of given limit example 10.
this can be fetch upto 10 time ie. 10 * limit=10 =100

```
[
    {
        "_fields": {
            //some data
        }
    },
    {
        "_fields": {
            //some data
        }
    },
    {
        "_count": 3,
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/orderLine/lists/_generic?_fields=_all&_limit=3",

            },
            {
                "rel": "next",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/orderLine/lists/_generic?_fields=_all&_limit=3&Company=32&orderLine=79",

            },
            {
                "rel": "prev",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/orderLine/lists/_generic?_fields=_all&_limit=3&Company=82&orderLine=23",

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

i've found the answer

```
Page<OrderLineDTO> toPage(List<OrderLineDTO> list, int pagesize, int pageNo) {

    int totalpages = list.size() / pagesize;
        PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(pageNo, pagesize);

        int max = pageNo>=totalpages? list.size():pagesize*(pageNo+1);
        int min = pageNo >totalpages? max:pagesize*pageNo;

        logger.info("totalpages{} pagesize {} pageNo {}   list size {} min {}   max {} ...........", totalpages,pagesize, pageNo, list.size(),
                min, max);
        Page<OrderLineDTO> pageResponse = new PageImpl<OrderLineDTO>(list.subList(min, max), pageable,
                list.size());
        return pageResponse;
    }
```

and call your method from your service

```
Page<OrderLineDTO> page = toPage(listPOL, pagesize), pageno));
```